# How to retain objects with a specific unique attribute in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array like so:

```
var myarray = [
    {"scaleId":"001","currentWeight":0.200}
    {"scaleId":"002","currentWeight":0.300},
    {"scaleId":"001","currentWeight":0.255},
    {"scaleId":"002","currentWeight":0.000},
    {"scaleId":"003","currentWeight":0.340},
    ]
```

and I want to retain the objects which have unique scaleId. So, for the above example, the output would like ( any random object can be retained if the scaleId is duplicate):

```
myarray = [
    {"scaleId":"001","currentWeight":0.200}
    {"scaleId":"002","currentWeight":0.300},
    {"scaleId":"003","currentWeight":0.340},
    ]
```

I'm already using underscore library in my application, so I'm fine with the implementation using underscore. I had come up with a solution but it is not working as expected. So, any help will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce` and inside callback check if in accumulator object there is a key with same scaleId. If so then add the value to that key. Finally use `Object.values` to create an array of values

```js
var myarray = [{
    "scaleId": "001",
    "currentWeight": 0.200
  },
  {
    "scaleId": "002",
    "currentWeight": 0.300
  },
  {
    "scaleId": "001",
    "currentWeight": 0.255
  },
  {
    "scaleId": "002",
    "currentWeight": 0.000
  },
  {
    "scaleId": "003",
    "currentWeight": 0.340
  }
]

let data = myarray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc[curr.scaleId]) {
    acc[curr.scaleId] = curr
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map`s and `Set`s are often the appropriate structures to maintain uniqueness.  Here is a simple function that uses a `Map` to maintain a single unique value given a property name:

```js
const uniqByProp = (prop) => (xs) =>
  [... new Map (xs .map ((x) => [x [prop], x])) .values ()]

var myarray = [{scaleId: "001", currentWeight: 0.200}, {scaleId: "002", currentWeight: 0.300}, {scaleId: "001", currentWeight: 0.255}, {scaleId: "002", currentWeight: 0.000}, {scaleId: "003", currentWeight: 0.340}]

console .log (
  uniqByProp ('scaleId') (myarray)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This version keeps the last matching value.  If you want the first matching one, it would be only slightly more complex.

Comment: Out of interest, is there a resource I can read about the particular code style you use? I don't see this used often, though I'm aware it's common among those that favor FP.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: I'm not sure what about my style interests you.  I am an FP fan, so I guess I'm matching some stereotype!  I prefer [curried functions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+currying).  I prefer simple single-purpose but ideally generic functions, but that just seems common sense to me.  I'm willing to write fairly wide lines, but I like some unusual whitespace (e.g. `xs .map (...)` rather than `xs.map(...)`, but that's a minor idiosyncracy more than a consistent style.  Or is it something else?

Comment: It was the whitespace usage I was noting particularly. There's no standard for that then? I've seen that used quite consistently when FP-oriented people write JavaScript.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts.  I know of no styleguide that suggests it.  I borrowed it and some other formatting ideas from [another SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633183/) who has since changed whitespace style.  Posts from that user contain a wealth of useful techniques.  The formatting is clearly derived from LISP-like language formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way (if you are using ES6/ES2015 or later)
Using Set to filter unique scaleIds first and feeding a new array with the Array.find method

```
var myarray = [
    {"scaleId":"001","currentWeight":0.200},
    {"scaleId":"002","currentWeight":0.300},
    {"scaleId":"001","currentWeight":0.255},
    {"scaleId":"002","currentWeight":0.000},
    {"scaleId":"003","currentWeight":0.340},
]

let scaleIds = [...new Set(myarray.map(item => item.scaleId))];
let filtered = []
scaleIds.forEach(scaleId => filtered.push(myarray.find(item => item.scaleId === scaleId)))

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`Array.prototype.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) to simplify aggregation logic:

```js
let myarray = [
  { scaleId: '001', currentWeight: 0.2 },
  { scaleId: '002', currentWeight: 0.3 },
  { scaleId: '001', currentWeight: 0.255 },
  { scaleId: '002', currentWeight: 0 },
  { scaleId: '003', currentWeight: 0.34 }
];

myarray = Object.values(
  myarray.reduceRight(
    (acc, cur) => (acc[cur.scaleId] = cur, acc),
    {}
  )
).reverse(); // optional if order of output matters to you

console.log(myarray);
```

or construct a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from key-value pairs generated using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let myarray = [
  { scaleId: '001', currentWeight: 0.2 },
  { scaleId: '002', currentWeight: 0.3 },
  { scaleId: '001', currentWeight: 0.255 },
  { scaleId: '002', currentWeight: 0 },
  { scaleId: '003', currentWeight: 0.34 }
];

myarray = Array.from(
  new Map(
    myarray.map(
      val => [val.scaleId, val]
    ).reverse()
  ).values()
).reverse(); // optional if order of output matters to you

console.log(myarray);
```

We use [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) on the array passed to the constructor to ensure that the insertion order allows earlier values to take precedence over later values.